# Visual Studio 2015: C++ code analysis error C1253, unable to load model file 'res://mspft140.dll/300'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, code-analysis, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 Community update 3, trying the C++ code analysis feature. The settings are as follows:

- `solution properties > code analysis settings > [all configurations] [all platforms] : microsoft native recommended settings`
- `project properties > code analysis > [all configurations] [all platforms] : microsoft native recommended settings`

Whenever I run `analyze > run code analysis on solution` I would always get a **`c1xx : fatal error C1253: Unable to load model file 'res://mspft140.dll/300'`**. This happens to every project, new or existing. MSDN is [not particularly helpful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/hh568711.aspx) about this one.

The string is a [res protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740(v=vs.85).aspx), so I checked if the dll mentioned is at its correct location (there are two actually, at `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\` and `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64`), and opened them with **resedit**. Both contain an XML resource named `300`, so I don't see any reason for VS being unable to load it. Resetting the settings didn't help, full uninstall and reinstall (half a day wasted) did neither.

I also ran **procmon** with `[Path] [contains] [mspft]` filter while running the code analysis in VS, but the file system results are only `SUCCESS` and `FILE LOCKED WITH ONLY READERS`, which [seems to be ok](http://forum.sysinternals.com/getting-parameter-data-for-failed-ntfs-calls_topic21378_post112976.html#112976).

Did anyone experience this error? Does anyone have any surmises about its cause?

---

**Update**: After looking thoroughly through many more procmon captures with different filters I found out that `cl.exe` tries to open this registry key value: `HKCR\PROTOCOLS\Handler\res\CLSID`. Clearly it looks for the handler of the `res` protocol mentioned in the error output - and it's not there to be found, while many siblings of `res` key refer to some valid handlers, for example, `http` key has `CLSID` value of `{79eac9e2-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b}`. I guess that my quest for now is figuring out what that `res` `CLSID` is meant to be.

Comment: Disable your anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: It was already disabled, but thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right in my assumption about the `res` protocol handler. The correct `HKCR\PROTOCOLS\Handler\res\CLSID` value is **`{3050f3bc-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b}`** (which refers to `C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.dll`). For some reason my registry was missing it; as soon as I added the value, the code analysis started working without errors.

I hope this helps someone, although I believe the bug is extremely rare.